# What is logic behind the output of following code?

Tags: c

I executed following piece of code:

```
int a[] = {5,1,15,20,25};
int i,j,m;
i = ++a[1];
j = a[1]++;
m = a[i++];
printf("%d %d %d",i,j,m);
```

and I got output as follow :-

```
3 2 15
```

The part which I don't understand is how I got value of `i` as **3**

It should be **2** right?

Or is it related with C compiler's right to left evaluation of `printf()` statement?

Comment: That's a nice lesson in how not to write C code.

Comment: @NateC-K To be fair, the code was likely intended to teach the mechanics of C, not as an example of what to do in production. A productive C programmer must understand both the typical idiom and the dark corners of the language.

Comment: @user4815162342: It was obvious that it's just an exercise in mentally computing the program result. But it's also an object lesson in how abuse of the ++ operator leads to unreadable code.

Comment: @NateC-K The snippet is intentionally obfuscated, which makes it unreadable by definition, but that's not the lesson. In fact, the line that the OP apparently missed is in fact not unreadable at all to a C programmer — `m = a[i++]` is a standard C idiom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `m = a[i++]` line incremented `i` for a second time, from 2 to 3.

Answer (score 1):

What is `a[1]`? It's 1. What's is `++a[1]`? It's 2. `i` is now 2, so far so good.

But when you calculate `m`, you have `a[i++];`, `i` now is 3 (Note that `m` will be `a[2]` - `i` increments *after* the evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

```
i = ++a[1];
```

Pre-increment operator. `a[1]` becomes 2, then `i` becomes 2;

```
j = a[1]++;
```

Post-incement operator. `j` becomes 2, then `a[1]` becomes 3.

```
m = a[i++];
```

Post-increment operator. `m` becomes `a[2]` = 15, then `i` becomes 3.